# Surface area of curved figure

Tags: polar-coordinates, surface-integrals

### **SOLVED**

I have a task: **calculate surface area**. There is given next expressions:
$$z=x^2+y^2\quad z^2\leq xy\quad x\geq 0 \quad y\geq 0$$
This look like this from above: [view from above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ealQM.png)

And like this from below: [view from below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aqCH.png)

I think they ask to calculate surface area of this little green petal below.

So, I've calculated the surface element expression:
$$\sqrt{8r^2+1}*dA$$
And limitations in polar coordinates:
$$-\sqrt{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}} \leq r\leq \sqrt{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}$$
$$r\sin{\theta} \geq 0$$
$$r\cos{\theta} \geq 0$$
How this limitation looks ( turquoise line - less than $r$, blue line - larger than $r$): [limitation][3]

Finally we get:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}d\theta \int_{0}^{\sqrt{\cos{\theta}\sin{\theta}}} \sqrt{8r^2+1}*r*dr = \frac{(15^\frac{3}{2}+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Please give your answer in the answer space, not in the original question to make sure that your question is already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surface of the sphere bounded by the hyperbolic sheet.

$dS = (-\frac {\partial z}{\partial x},\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}, 1)\\(-2x,-2y,1)\\
\|dS\| = \sqrt {4x^2+4y^2+1}$

The boundary of the intersection of the two surfaces.

$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = xy$

Convert to cylindrical

$r^4 = r^2(\sin\theta\cos\theta)\\
r = \sqrt {\sin\theta\cos\theta}\\
r = \sqrt {\frac 12 \sin 2\theta}$

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\int_0^{\sqrt {\frac 12 \sin 2\theta}} r\sqrt{4r^2+1} \ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: Pretty bad things happening after you start solving this integral

Comment: Looks like you are going to get an elliptical integral.

Comment: Yeah, so I cant get a certain value for this integral?